# Interesting theorem in differential geometry

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors, general-relativity

I was reading a while back in differential geometry, and noticed a theorem which states something along the lines of that for any given manifold there always exists a point where the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ is equal to $g^{i}_{j}$ and so the derivative with respect to any coordinate is just 0. There was a transformation involved, I believe it is called the exponential map, may someone please explain why that map was used?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense (at least to me), but perhaps you're looking for "normal coordinates" or "Riemannian normal coordinates".

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. As Matt suggested, you're talking about normal coordinates. At every point $p$, you can choose local coordinates so that $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ *at*  $p$ and so that the derivatives $\partial g_{ij}/\partial x^k(p)=0$. This requires knowledge of geodesics and the exponential mapping.